# Separate text in cells and decompose into different columns depending on the content

Tags: python, pandas, split

how can i take date from rec event and from visit event and put it in different columns?

as you can see, there can be more than 2 events (not only rec and visit). Moreover, they can be interchanged

i have DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'event': ['rec - 2022-11-13 21:07:51, visit - 2022-11-16 10:01:01',
                           'visit - 2022-11-14 15:34:28, rec - 2022-11-12 09:03:58',
                           'rec - 2022-11-13 15:13:16, visit - 2022-11-14 12:15:01',
                            'rec - 2022-11-17 15:13:17, call - 2022-11-20 12:11:01 visit - 2022-11-21 12:15:01'],
                    'id':[17, 34, 36, 11]})
```

i need DF

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'rec': ['2022-11-13', '2022-11-12', '2022-11-13', '2022-11-17'],
                   'visit': ['2022-11-16', '2022-11-14', '2022-11-14', '2022-11-21'],
                    'id': [17, 34, 36, 11]})
```

i can't just `split(', ')[0]` and `split(', ')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me, I needed to apply several splits given the input data:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'event': ['rec - 2022-11-13 21:07:51, visit - 2022-11-16 10:01:01',
                           'visit - 2022-11-14 15:34:28, rec - 2022-11-12 09:03:58',
                           'rec - 2022-11-13 15:13:16, visit - 2022-11-14 12:15:01',
                            'rec - 2022-11-17 15:13:17, call - 2022-11-20 12:11:01 visit - 2022-11-21 12:15:01'],
                    'id':[17, 34, 36, 11]})

liste = df['event'].str.split(',', 1).tolist()

rec = []
visit = []
for lst in liste:
    rec.append([i.strip() for i in lst if i.strip().startswith('rec')])
    visit.append([i.strip() for i in lst if not i.strip().startswith('rec')])

rec = [i[0].split('rec - ')[1].split(' ')[0] for i in rec]
visit = [i[0].split('visit - ')[1].split(' ')[0] for i in visit]
df['rec'] = rec
df['visit'] = visit
```